# retrieve image from database

Tags: android

I got null when I am trying to convert bytearray into bitmap. I don't know why. please give me useful suggestions.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newscreen);
    TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView age = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase(
            "StudentData.db"
            , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
            , null
        );

    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);

    Cursor cur = db.query("stuData", 
                null, null, null, null, null, null);
            //cur.moveToFirst();
    cur.moveToFirst();
        //name.setText(cur.getString(1));
        //age.setText(cur.getString(2));

       // if(bb!=null)
        //{


        //ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb);
            //bs = new BufferedInputStream(bb)

        //img.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize=5;
            name.append("n" + cur.getString(1));
            byte[] bb = cur.getBlob(3);


            System.out.print("DAta"+bb);

            for(int i =0;i<bb.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(bb[i]);
            }
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cur.getBlob(3),0,cur.getBlob(3).length);

            img.setImageBitmap(theImage);

            cur.moveToNext();
        }
    cur.close();
```

Comment: Completely agree with @Vladimir, if you didn't receive a single good answer yet for any of your 21 questions you asked here, I wonder why you keep asking them on SO!?

Answer (score 0):

there are few points to check.

1. are you inserting the correct image byte array to DB? check the length of array
2. On retriving from DB, check the length of array retrived.
3. Also check weather the array is null or not.

Comment: I already checked all these things rohit, there is no any misconception.